# How to bind a function to a select when is changed regardless how

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind a function to a select with javascript. I can do it with onchange or .change(). However, it seems that my function is not being triggered if the change has done programmatically:

e.g.

```
<select id='selectId' onChange;"javascript:console.log('changed - onchange')">
```

```js
jQuery( "#selectId" ).change(function() {
   console.log( "changed - .change()" );
});

jQuery('#selectId').val("2").change()      //(a)
jQuery('#selectId').val("1");              //(b)
```

If the user changes the select value, and in the case (a) the triggers will work. However, the second case will not be detected.

How can I make the binding, so it will detect the case (b) too.

Comment: You could prototype the jQuery `val()` function to automatically trigger a `change` event, if the element is a `select`. I would personally just use option A though.

Comment: bind to `$(document) .onChange("id", callback)` it will work

Comment: `[...]The change event is fired [...] when a change to the element's value is committed by the user.[...]` So whenever you change the value programmatically you would need to trigger the event yourself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No need to patch prototype, as there is `valHook` available for select element that can be extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [`$.fn.val`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.val) doesn't trigger change event itself. The simplest thing you can do is to trigger it manually when you need it. If however you *really* want it to happen automatically you can extend `valHook` setter of the select element:

```
$.valHooks.select.set = function(orig) {
    return function(el) {
        var result = orig.apply(this, arguments);
        $(el).trigger('change');
        return result;
    };
}($.valHooks.select.set);
```

This seems to work fine. You just take original hook and complement it with triggering code.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cq07fL29/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.trigger()`:

```
jQuery('#selectId').val("2").trigger("change");
```

EDIT:
  Following the tip from `@Rory McCrossan` you can extend the val() function to trigger the event if it's a select element

```
  // Save old val
  var oldVal = $.fn.val;
  $.fn.val = function(value) {
      // Execute parent val() 
      obj = oldVal.apply(this, arguments);

      // If it is a select
      if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(this.get(0)) == '[object HTMLSelectElement]') {
          // Trigger the event
          this.trigger("change");
      }
      return obj;
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#selectId').val("v3");
  });
```

here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cvtx7g3o/)